# Deploying on firebase gives welcome screen

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I got this message after deploying app on firebase.
[image: after deployment to firebase]

This is my firebase JSON file :

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "y",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]}}
```

Here is my index.js file in root folder:

```
import React from "react";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "App";

const container = document.getElementById("root");

// Create a root.
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This instruction in your `firebase.json` file:

```
"public": "y",
```

This indicates to the Firebase CLI that it should deploy the files in the subfolder named `y` to Firebase Hosting. And since you don't have any directory `y`, it deploys no files and you end up with the default website.

The solution is to configure the correct folder name. Since you say that your files are in the same directory as `firebase.json`, that'd be:

```
"public": ".",
```